# What is equivalent statement of DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)(which give sql statement for current connection otr specified connection) in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the **MySQL equivalent** statement of `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)`, which lists the sql statement for current connection or specified connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SHOW PROFILES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html) to see a list of the most recent statements sent to MySQL:

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

If you want/need to see currently running queries, use [SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html):

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

The `FULL` keyword means the list will include queries from all clients, not just the one you are running the command on.

Comment: beacuse i want sql statement for audot purpose.if i can get it from trigger then i will be fine.

Comment: The FULL keyword means the list will include queries from all clients, not just the one you are running the command on.
----- So how can we get for only current process?

Comment: What do you mean by "current process"?  If the query has finished executing, use `SHOW PROFILES`.  If it is still running, use `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. There are links to the documentation.