# What's the equivalent of mysql's 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

We're in the process of converting to `SQL Server` from `MySQL`.  I'm trying to figure out why a call to `sqsh` isn't returning and I suspect that there's some lock I don't know about.

How do you find out what's going on (preferably via the database connection)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939001/what-is-equivalent-statement-of-dbcc-inputbufferspidwhich-give-sql-statemen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can look into sp_who and sp_who2 to see if they give you what you need. Otherwise, SQL Profiler can often help with problem diagnoses.

Comment: For newbies: `exec sp_who` or `exec sp_who2`

Answer (score 19):

**Try this**

```
select * from master..sysprocesses
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server includes a few undocumented procs. `sp_who2` lists all current processes connected to a SQL Server. It's located in the `master` database.

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_who2;
GO
```