# Is there an equivalent to 'mysqladmin processlist' for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, processlist

I've been trying to formulate a query to help myself identify resource-heavy queries/database/users using SQL Server and haven't gotten it down quite yet.  I want to build a query that will do what 'mysqladmin processlist' would do for MySQL.

I've referred to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052314/whats-the-equivalent-of-mysqls-show-processlist-on-sql-server) but haven't gotten what I really need from it.  I'm using `sp_who`, `sp_who2` and queries like this:

```
select master.dbo.sysprocesses.loginame, 
count(master.dbo.sysprocesses.loginame)
from master.dbo.sysprocesses
group by master.dbo.sysprocesses.loginame
```

The problem always is that one of these tools doesn't give me everything I need.   My goal would be to have a query that would be of this format:

```
LOGIN, DATABASE, QUERY, CPU, MEM, etc.
```

If anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate the help.  If anyone has any SQL Server DBA cheatsheets that would be great, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it *have to* be done with a sproc call? [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) (the link is for the express edition, but a full install of SQL Server already has it) has an "Activity Monitor" feature which lists exactly what you want.

Other than that,

```
EXECUTE sp_who2
```

Gives you exactly what you asked for: Login, DBName, Command, CPUTime, DiskIO, are all there...

If you want the *exact* command that a SPID is executing, you can use the

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid)
```

command (`sp_who2` just tells you whether it's a DELETE, SELECT, etc)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a sproc call.. in fact I do use Activity Monitor right now.  I wonder if there is a way for me to determine WHAT query is being run, though?  That way I figure out which queries are causing problems.

Comment: In Activity monitor, you can right-click a process and choose "Details" to get the command that's being run. Or `DBCC INPUTBUFFER`, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you bust out `sp_who2`, you could extract the fields that you're interested in:

```
select    
  spid
 ,status 
 ,hostname
 ,program_name
 ,cmd
 ,cpu
 ,physical_io
 ,blocked
 ,dbid
 ,convert(sysname, rtrim(loginame))
        as loginname

      from sys.sysprocesses with (nolock)
      order by cpu desc
```