# mysql how to see most common queries (Lamp server, cpanel whm)

Tags: mysql

I have a server and many websites, i want to see the most common queries so that to optimize them.

Do you know any tool or any way to collect some statistics ? Thank you

Comment: What kind of server do you have? What platform?

Comment: Are you sure you have any single query which is common for the 2 different websites?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939001/what-is-equivalent-statement-of-dbcc-inputbufferspidwhich-give-sql-statemen

Comment: I don't think you understood what i want. I have a server, many queries from many websites,

I just want the queries that are executed more often

Answer (score 7):

Since in your last question you seemed to be uninterested in solutions that you don't already have installed, here's a solution that uses only common POSIX commands:

```
grep 'Query' general-query.log |
  sed -e 's/.* Query       //'  |
  sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Depending on the size of your MySQL general query log, this might take a while to run.

Comment: PS: there's a literal tab character after `Query` in the sed command, but it got expanded into spaces when I pasted the command.

Comment: not good "select * from users where user = 'nikos'"
and "select * from users where user = 'andreas'"

for my purpose is the same querie

How do i generate the general-query.log ?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html for information on how to configure MySQL to output the general query log.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about all queries, but you can log slow queries for optimization

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: I don't have any slow sql queries because the limit for mysql slow is seconds, and no query is more than a second